# Can X-rays be used for communication?

Tags: optical

I keep increasing my frequencies and want to get up the spectrum more and more. My current project is pointing a powerful focused LED from a peak and I will try to pick it up with a telescope and some sort of photo detector to receive the AM light.

I keep wondering about even higher frequencies. I am assuming Ultra violet should not be too much more difficult than Light unless the air absorbs that band.

So, going higher, could x-rays be used to communicate, maybe just CW or is it not possible at all and x-rays will not propagate.

Comment: PWM modulate the transmitting LED. Slow detector response will detect it as an AM signal. As a side note, many LED's respond to their own frequencies, and so can be used for both transmit and receive.

Comment: I'm really not sure this is the right stack; more of a physics/electronics stack type of question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can control its emissions, and detect it, then you can use it for communications. X-rays are no exception.

However there are many reasons they are not widely used, including expensive and limited optics, short distance line of sight outside a vacuum, and not as safe as many other forms of communications.

Still X-rays have some uses and there are [X-ray communication systems](http://gsfctechnology.gsfc.nasa.gov/TechSheets/XRAY_Goddard_Final.pdf) in development. They can be used over vast distances in space with relatively low power, can communicate with spacecraft during re-entry when traditional communications are disrupted due to electron activity in the heat of re-entry, and can penetrate some types of RF shielding, which has some interesting use cases.

Comment: Not to mention required compliance with the Federal Food, Drug and Cosmetic Act (FFDCA), Chapter V, Subchapter C - Electronic Product Radiation Control.

Comment: X-ray transmitters can also be used to implement an [IP over demographics](http://xkcd.com/190/) network.